# Slow hazelcast migration when using index

Tags: hazelcast

I'm running a microservice in a openshift environment using hazelcast 4.1.1 and the 2.2.1 kubernetes discovery plugin. I have configured hazelcast in embedded mode and I'm running 4 instances of that service. When I scale down the application from 4 to 3 pods the whole migration does not finish and my application throws exception due to WrongTargetException all the time (after one minute).

I analyzed the diagnostic file and I believe that the error comes from the index calculation. If I disable all my indices on my maps, everthing works like a charm. I think this might be related to https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/18079

It seems that the deserialization of my objects are called for each index separatly. Since we have configured a custom (de-)serializer which also applies some compression (LZ4) the migration takes ages.

Can somebody confirm my assumtions? Or are there any other known issues with index calculation and migration?

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you run the same application on a bare-metal server (not in Kubernetes)?

Comment: Thats difficult to setup. I can try to startup the application on my local machine, but i guess im going to reach the memory limits... I'll give it a try. Btw: we are talking about 2'500'000 entries using about 3Gb memory in binary